# external mail server desn't receive email to self domain

Tags: email, mail-server, email-server

I have an external mail server that I use and works just fine. I have a website on another server with a php contact form that sends email to my own domain. The problem is that the server takes that email as a local one and tries to deliver it within the same server. So the email never arrives because my mail server is different one.
The issue is probably some bad configuration on my website server.
ps. If i change the email in the php code with my gmail account it works just fine What can I do to sole this issue?

thanks

Comment: What kind of email server and on what operating system?

Answer (score 1):

if it is using postfix, check /etc/postfix/main.cf (most redhat 6 uses it by default)

In the file there is a line to configure relayhost, so just put the IP address of your mail server there.